# Home Web Server Server Does Not Correctly Respond to SSH, MySQL, etc

Tags: networking, ssh, mysql, ubuntu-12.04

I am attempting to setup my home web server (Ubuntu Server 12.04) such that I can ssh to it from outside of my home network as well as connect to the MySQL databases that I have created on it.

Currently, I know that port 80 is responding correctly to requests. I have Apache running on it, so there are no problems there. However, when I try to SSH to the server, I do not get a response, nor do I get one when I connect to it on port 3306 via MySQL (ERROR 2003, Can't connect to server (10060)). I can use phpmyadmin to connect from my browser, but this is not useful for connecting via PHP.

I have port forwarding set up for ports 80, 22 and 3306, but I do not know what else I should do. Please forgive me if the answer is obvious/simple to obtain - I have been trying to fix this for months.

*Edit*

The output of `netstat -atn | grep [port]` for ports 22 and 3306 are as follows:

(22)

```
tcp    0    0 0.0.0:22           0.0.0.0:*          Listen
tcp    0    0 127.0.0.1:53822    127.0.0.1:40896    Established 
tcp    0    0 127.0.0.1:40896    127.0.0.1:53822    Established 
tcp6   0    0 :::22              :::*               Listen
```

(3306)

```
tcp    0    0 0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:*          Listen
```

Thank you.

Comment: Also, I do not believe that this issue is too localized. I have seen many posts about this issue around the Internet, but most were not solved.

Comment: Lots of possibilities - misconfigured port forwarding, blocked ports by your ISP, etc.  There's nothing odd that phpmyadmin works - once you've connected to it at port 80, everything else is happening locally on the web server/intranet, so it doesn't need ports to the outside world . . .

Comment: What type of firewall are you using?

Comment: Well @ernie if there's anything that I can provide that would help you to help me solve this, I would appreciate if you would let me know... 
I am only using the default ufw, Jim G

Comment: Do an external port scan to verify 22 is open. On the server, verify the ssh daemon is running and netsat to make sure sure its actually listening for connections

Comment: Seeing how you've configured your port forwarding, as well as a port scan of the outside address (e.g. https://www.grc.com/shieldsup‎, http://www.canyouseeme.org/, etc) would be useful.  Obviously verifying you can connect to the services via the intranet would also help.

Comment: Well here's a start: the port scan shows that neither port is returning a service. My router is forwarding the ports, however, so I'll try verifying that with netstat

Comment: netstat -atn | grep 22 or Netstat -atn | grep -i listening

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: 1. What is your router model? maybe there is issues with it 2. Can you post output of `sudo iptables -L` Also i wouldn't open mysql to the internet, tunnel that thru ssh and change your ssh port to something nonstandard, unless you like filling your auth.log with hack attempts :)

Comment: Hi Phil. I will take your suggestion as soon as I can get it working! And my router is from Linksys (Model WRT54GS). The output of that command can be found here: http://nmagerko.me/iptables

Answer (score 0):

SSH - Make sure that you install the SSH Server

`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

MYSQL - Make sure that you allow outside connections

`sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment out `bind-address` if you want to grant access to outside connections.

You will need to make sure that the user that you are connecting to MySQL has access from outside of the localhost address.

Comment: Unfortunately, all of this has already been done. I've had the ssh server for a while, and the bind address is commented out. All users have both local and % access to the server. 
It would seem that the problem is that the requests are not going "through" the ports

Answer (score 0):

Check your router's firewall settings and make sure that ports 22, 80 and 3306 are open.

Port-forwarding often doesn't automatically open the ports on your router's firewall - I realise that it seems silly and trivial, but I was bitten by this bug on one of my previous home routers (Orange UK's LiveBox).

Comment: I will certainly check this out now

Comment: I disabled the firewall completely, but apparently nothing changed :/ Very good suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

Wow UFW does a lovely mess of iptables,
It looks to me that ssh is not unblocked on the firewall use

```
sudo ufw status
```

to see whats allowed or blocked and try

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

i found a nice guide here http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/firewall-ubuntu-servers/ which you might take a look at, alternatively i use the old tried and tested method of generating a bash iptables script (from http://www.mista.nu/iptables/) and run it at boot from rc.local.